# Luks encrypted Manjaro with Bitlocker encrypted Win11 dualboot

Tags: windows, dual-boot, lvm, manjaro, luks

As I'm new to UNIX this might be a stupid question but here we go.
I want to install manjaro next to my win11 which I have bitlocker encrypted. I need to keep the Win11 installation as is.

I reduced the win partition to free up space for my manjaro and I now want to have my linux to be in two partitions, /root and /home. Both should be encrypted using LUKS but I don't want them to have two separate passwords so for what I understood I'd need an encrypted LVM containing the root and home partition which stay ext4 right?

So basically what I want is

```
- SSD
-- UEFI
-- win reserved stuff
-- bitlocker win11
-- ?LVM LUKS encrypted?
--- /root
--- /home
-- shared ntfs (which in the end I'd like to encrypt with truecrypt to be accessible from win11 and manjaro)
```

but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track here. Any advice?

edit: as the laptop has 16GB RAM I suppose I won't need swap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As I'm new to UNIX

<strike>In that case you should probably pick a distribution with a GUI installer that can do the partitioning with encryption automatically. But if you want Manjaro, go ahead, but it will be more complicated.</strike>

Edit: Actually, [Calamares supports LUKS encryption](https://technical-news.net/linux-calamares-installer-23-encrypted-with-luks1613705837) so if you don't have another reason to do this manually, I would strongly recommend using the automatic partitioning with disk encryption.

> in two partitions, /root and /home

The correct mount point for the root filesystem is `/`, `/root` is home directory for the root user.

> Both should be encrypted using LUKS but I don't want them to have two separate passwords

If you want to use partitions you can create two separate LUKS partitions and use the same password, during the boot process you'll need to enter it only once.

> so for what I understood I'd need an encrypted LVM containing the root and home partition which stay ext4 right?

LVM is a layered storage. You'll need to create single partition with `fdisk` or `parted`, create LUKS on it with `cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdxY` and `cryptsetup luksOpen <luks name>` (same as with normal partition), then create LVM volume group on top of the LUKS device with `vgcreate <vg name> /dev/mapper/<luks name>` and then create two logical volumes with `lvcreate -n <name> -L <size> <vg name>`. [RHEL documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_logical_volumes/assembly_configuring-lvm-volumes-configuring-and-managing-logical-volumes) is a good source for LVM and ArchWiki also has a nice [page with disk encryption](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system) description.

Don't forget that with LVM, separate `/boot` partition is usually recommended. `/boot` can be encrypted but requires [special setup](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#Encrypted_boot_partition_(GRUB)).

> shared ntfs (which in the end I'd like to encrypt with truecrypt to be accessible from win11 and manjaro)

BitLocker is also supported in Linux (you'll need cryptsetup 2.3.0 or newer and you'll need to create a password protected BitLocker volume or use recovery passphrase, TPM is not supported) so you don't need TrueCrypt if you don't want it for other reasons.

Comment: Ok so then it seems that I don't need LVM afterall. I thought it was used to encrypt several partitions at once. Following your advice it worked! Even though I now don't have the option to boot into windows. I suppose I have to change something in the uefi partition?